# jsx syntax about curly brace

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> First one

I am confused about  the use of curly braces. `const { a } = { b : 5 };`

What is going on about this code.

I put it to babel, it translate to javascript.

In javascript,

```
let a = { b : 5 };

let b = a.b;
```

In javascript, I could say

1. declare a and reference to the Object `{b:5}`
2. then declare b and reference to the value of Object `a = {b:5}`, property `b: 5`

But when I see `const { a } = { b : 5 };` , I do not have any sense to it.

I can not say anything to it.

I have know about `{}` use to javascript Expression. But, I still can not understand it.

> Another one is below

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Welcome extends Component;
```

and

```
import React from 'react';

class Welcome extends React.Component
```

I am not sure the code above is right or not. It's just curly brace confused me.

Because second line

`extends Component;`

`extends React.Component;`

I do not know how the curly brace is going on.

Comment: It called **Destructuring assignment**. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple words. we use {abc} when we want to import a particular function from a file. 
so if you are writing import react then you will have to use React.component because class extends React.component and not whole React .

Answer (score 1):

Destructuring is a javaScript feature that allows us to extract multiple pieces of data from an array or object and assign them to their own variables.

Destructuring works similarly in class components, with slightly different syntax.

```
class Attraction extends React.Component {
  render() {  
   return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Destructuring  made this code much DRYer and easier to read.